# Add calculated column to a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with two columns and I want to add a third column which will be column A divided by column B. I added a template field but I am getting a divide by zero error. How can I check for zero values to stop the error message?

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCalc" runat="server" >
          <%# Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("val1").ToString()) / Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("val2").ToString()) %>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you sure can. You can even do that inline, but that would clutter your markup too much, so I would suggest moving this code to code behind.

```
protected decimal Calculate(string a, string b)
{
    decimal ad = Convert.ToDecimal(a);
    decimal bd = Convert.ToDecimal(bd);

    if (bd == 0)
    {
        return 0; // or whatever
    }

    return ad / bd;
}
```

To call this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCalc" runat="server" >
    <%# Calculate(Eval("val1").ToString(), Eval("val2").ToString()) %>
</Label>
```

Comment: Second this approach, you have much more control in code behind.